# Combine Progress bar with talker.SpeakAsync finish time

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I just finished a project , which has a picture box with a onclick handler that speaks the text found in a richtextbox , i want to add a progress bar , starts with the press of the picture ( start of sound ) untill the end of the speaking. ( so i dnt want it to be timed by me , but by the speech itself )

all i did was a progress bar with a normal timer, how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using the SpeechSynthesizer from Microsoft. If this is the case you can handle the [SpeakProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speakprogress(v=vs.110).aspx) event inside your code and update the progress bar accordingly, most likely determining the percentage based on the CharacterCount and CharacterPosition of the [SpeakProgressEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speakprogresseventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) class that you will receive as a parameter on the handler.